# Gas/Steam turbine for power generation

Tags: power, electromagnetic, power-generation, synchronous-motor

I have a question regarding the electricity generation using either steam or gas turbine.

After the process of gas or steam accrues and the turbine rotates. the turbine which is connected to the synchronous generator using a shaft.

Here I do not fully understand how the turbine rotation is converted into electric energy.

Could someone explain me the process, I want to know if the turbine is connected to the stator or rotor and how the magnetic field will be induced.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the rotor is the part of the generator that turns, while the stator is fixed. So the turbine, which is turned by the steam/gas pressure, must be connected to the rotor. In a synchronous generator, the rotor has a fixed magnetic field. As the rotor is turned by the turbine, the field passing through the coils fixed to the stator changes and a changing voltage is induced in them. This voltage can be used to extract power from the generator.

Comment: Thank you and I want to ask something, we know that the rotor locked up with the stator and rotor with the same synchronous speed. Is it different in gas /steam turbine ?

Comment: @user34755: Generators work the same whether they are driven by steam turbines, steam piston engines, diesel engines or water turbines. (or anything else).